# Update claims in ClaimsPrincipal

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, adal

I am using Adal with Azure Active Directory and I need to add extra claims via custom OwinMiddleware.
When I add claims to this principal, I am able to access them in the current request. But after a page refresh, the claim is gone.

I thought Owin handled serialization of claims and put it into a cookie itself, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

I add the claims as follows:

```
 var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity) ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity;
        if (!claimsIdentity.IsAuthenticated) return;

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claimsIdentity);

        var currentTenantClaim = GetTenantClaim();

        if (currentTenantClaim != null)
            claimsIdentity.RemoveClaim(currentTenantClaim);

        claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.CurrentTenantId, id));

        context.Authentication.AuthenticationResponseGrant = new AuthenticationResponseGrant
            (new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), new AuthenticationProperties {IsPersistent = true});
```

Any ideas on how to persist the new claims to the cookie?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've added the claims to the wrong Identity. They had to be added to the identity variable instead of the claimsIdentity.

Working code:

```
        var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity) context.Authentication.User.Identity;
        if (!claimsIdentity.IsAuthenticated) return;

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claimsIdentity);

        var currentTenantClaim = GetTenantClaim(identity);

        if (currentTenantClaim != null)
            identity.RemoveClaim(currentTenantClaim);

        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.CurrentTenantId, id));

        context.Authentication.AuthenticationResponseGrant = new AuthenticationResponseGrant
            (new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), new AuthenticationProperties {IsPersistent = true});
```

Comment: This is what I exactly need to do. Can you please share your complete code? Thanks

Comment: What type is the `context` object (first line of your code sample)?

Answer (score 5):

This is what worked for me, using .NET 6:

```
var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)Request.HttpContext.User.Identity;
identity.AddClaim(new Claim("ClaimName", "ClaimValue"));
```

If I want to check this claim in this identity, this is what I do

```
var Claims = User.Claims;
```

Hope it might help someone