# Why is this code for adding claims to a ClaimsPrincipal correct?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I'm trying out manipulating claims in my web app using the `TransformAsync` method in my own implementation of `IClaimsTransformation`.

The example code in [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/claims?view=aspnetcore-7.0#extend-or-add-custom-claims-using-iclaimstransformation) looks like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using System.Security.Claims;

public class MyClaimsTransformation : IClaimsTransformation
{
    public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity();
        var claimType = "myNewClaim";
        if (!principal.HasClaim(claim => claim.Type == claimType))
        {
            claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(claimType, "myClaimValue"));
        }

        principal.AddIdentity(claimsIdentity);
        return Task.FromResult(principal);
    }
}
```

I understand that, as the documentation states, "This method might get called multiple times", so in my version, as in the example, I'm ensuring that I check for the presence of each claim before adding it.

I seem to be ending up in a situation where this method is called and my `ClaimsPrincipal` has multiple `ClaimsIdentity`s. I'm trying to get around it by adding this line at the beginning of my method (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74385922/1483190)):

```
ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = principal.Identity != null ? (ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity : new ClaimsIdentity();
```

What I really want to know, though, is why Microsoft's example code is correct in creating a new `ClaimsIdentity` and adding it to the `ClaimsPrincipal` each time. It seems intuitive that that would lead to the `ClaimsPrincipal` having multiple identities if the method is getting called repeatedly, but apparently that isn't the case (in which case, why?), or Microsoft's example is flawed. Why does it not attempt to add the new claim to the existing `ClaimsIdentity` rather than creating a new one each time?

Answer (score 0):

> It seems intuitive that that would lead to the ClaimsPrincipal having
> multiple identities

In asp.net core ,`ClaimsPrincipal` represents User,`ClaimsIdentity` represents  something that could provide User's info, such as  User's credit card/ google account/passport..... ,`ClaimsPrincipal` could hold multiple `ClaimsIdentity`,
and it's ok  to create a new `ClaimsIdentity` to hold the custom claim that shouldn't exist in other `ClaimsIdentity`

Comment: I understand that, but the `TransformAsync` method gets called repeatedly by the authentication middleware, and every time, even if no new claims are added, it still appears to add a new `ClaimsIdentity` every time in the example code I posted.